# How to keep same parameters after reloading page/view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a select tag dropdown of a few options and I want to have the page reload with the same option selected when the user selects an option.

So far, I have the following code:

`<select name="blah" id="blahblah" onchange="document.location.reload()">`

This will reload the page when an option is selected but how would I go about having the page reload with the same parameters/ option selected?

Comment: Side note: having a page refresh when a dropdown value changes sounds **very** irritating

Comment: yes, I would agree! It's because the view would have to change according to what dropdown they choose. Would there be a better way to do that instead??

Comment: You can bind in Javascript to the onchange event like you did, but instead of reloading the page just change whatever you want in the DOM, from JS without refreshing the page.
If you need data from the server you can make an ajax request.

Comment: Hmm okay, but I'm actually writing a ruby-on-rails app and I would want to have a different <%= submit_tag %> and I'm not sure how I would add that into the JS

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you currently have?